# Coding Style: Best way to program function calls dependent on some flag

Tags: c, coding-style

This is a simple C question. I designed my code like this:

```
main()
{
   ...
   do_my_func1();
   ...
}
```

Where do_my_func1() did this:

```
void do_my_func1()
{
   if (flag)
   {
      ..do the processing for this function
   }
}
```

My boss said this should actually be done like this:

```
main()
{
   ...
   if (flag)
   {
      do_my_func1();
   }
   ...
}

void do_my_func1()
{
   ..do the processing for this function
}
```

So what is the best practise in doing a function call like this - I thought my way was the best way especially if you're calling many functions dependent on many flags ?

Comment: The boss is always right :P

Comment: As a general rule, a function should do one job and do it well.  As a general rule, flags which cause a function to do one of two things are problematic.  As a general rule, global variables are frowned on, too.  But there are exceptions to all of these rules, so I would never make a global rule like "never have option flags" or "never use global variables".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function like your `do_my_func1()` should always stick to doing simple things and the checks to call it should be done beforehand, so 
   `if (flag)` should always be in the parent function.

Also a good practice is to add `static` in front of functions that are called within the same file, it lightens the compiled executable

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very good reason, you should definitely pick option your boss gave you. One alternative is this:

```
void do_my_func1(int flag)
{
   if (flag)
   {
      ..do the processing for this function
   }
}
```

What is best depends on the situation and cannot be determined in a general example like this.

Avoid globals when you can. There are some cases where they are good, but being lazy is not one of them. ;)

If there are very many flags, pack them into an array or a struct.

Answer (score 0):

In this case boss is right.
In your code there will always be a function call. Which is useless if flag is not set.
Checking condition takes much less time than calling a function. Calling a function requires lot of processing. ([link](https://qr.ae/TWsUds))
It's much easier to evaluate a condition.
In modern compiler branch prediction is more accurate and saves a lot of time by eliminating a function call.
You can make a small demo to verify this:
`

```
main()
{
   int n=INTMAX;
   int m=INTMAX;
   struct timeval start, stop;
   double msecs = 0;

   gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
   for(;n>0;n--){
       for(;m>0;m--){  
           if (flag)
           {
              do_my_func1();
           }
           ...
        }
    }
   gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
   msecs = (double)(stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0f + (double)(stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*1000.0f ;
   printf("time taken %f\n",msecs);
}

void do_my_func1()
{
   ..do the processing for this function
}`
```

v/s your version and record the time.